# How can I upgrade to postgres 9.5 from 9.3.4?

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres. I am using postgres 9.3.4. How can I upgrade to postgres 9.5 without losing my data? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Fine Manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/upgrading.html).

Essentially, you can either dump with `pg_dumpall` (use `pg_dumpall` from 9.5!) and restore with `psql`, or you can use `pg_upgrade` for an in-place upgrade (after you have made a backup).